# opening page multiple times bug

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

**future builder running multiple times and page opening multiple at the same time. How to fix this error?**

SubCategory StatefulWidget

```
  class subCategory extends StatefulWidget {
  final int RegId;
  final int AssetId;
  final String title;
  final int ParentId;
  final int equipmentId;

  subCategory(this.RegId, this.AssetId, this.title, this.ParentId,this.equipmentId, {Key key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _mainCategory();
}
```

_mainCategory State Widget

```
class _mainCategory extends State<subCategory> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: submitRequestAppBar(context),
      body: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey[350],
            leading: Container(),
            title: Text(
              widget.title,
              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              style:  TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black),),),
```

FutureBuilder inside Body

```
          body: FutureBuilder(
            future: getRegister1(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.none:
                  return Text('Press button to start.');
                case ConnectionState.active:
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return waitingCircle();
                case ConnectionState.done:
                  if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                  if (snapshot.data.length == 0)
                    return noResultFound();
                  else
                    return createListView(context, snapshot); }
              return null; // unreachable
            },)),); }
```

CreateListView Widget

```
  Widget createListView(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    List<SubCategoryItem> values = snapshot.data;
```

return ListView

```
    return ListView.builder(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, right: 0.0, left: 0.0),
      itemCount: 1,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return GridView.count(
          physics: ScrollPhysics(),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          crossAxisCount: 4,

          children: List.generate(values.length, (index) {
```

return GridTile

```
            return GridTile(
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => WoDescription2(
                            widget.RegId,
                            widget.AssetId,
                            widget.ParentId,
                            values[index].childId,
                            false,
                            1,
                            widget.title,
                        widget.equipmentId))),
```

Column Widget

```
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Card(
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(
                                color: Colors.blueAccent, width: 1.5)),
                        child: Stack(
                          children: <Widget>[
```

flutter_svg plugin use for svg images

```
                            SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/Defect/icon-${values[index].childId}.svg',
                              height: 50.0,),],),), ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Text(
                        '${values[index].description}',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0),),),],),), ); }),); },);}
```

FutureBuider future:getRegister1

```
  Future getRegister1() async {
    List<SubCategoryItem> description = [];
    List cat = [];

    var catLocal = (await HelperDatabase1().displayDefCatRelation());
    var defCatLocal = (await HelperDatabase1().display());

    for (int i = 0; i < catLocal.length; i++) {
      if (widget.RegId == catLocal[i].r &&
          widget.AssetId == catLocal[i].t &&
          widget.ParentId == catLocal[i].p) {
        cat.add(catLocal[i].c);}}

    for (int i = 0; i < cat.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < defCatLocal.length; j++) {
        if (cat[i] == defCatLocal[j].deF_CAT_ID) {

          var oneItem = SubCategoryItem(
              childId: defCatLocal[j].deF_CAT_ID,
              description: defCatLocal[j].description);
          await description.add(oneItem);}}}
    return description;}}
```

SubCategoryItem class

```
class SubCategoryItem {
  int childId;String description;
  SubCategoryItem({this.childId, this.description});}
```

[image]

Comment: why do you need 'await' on description.add(oneItem) ?
Isn't it the reason you build() method was called multiple times?

Comment: I check now. I removed await but nothing change

Answer (score 0):

Just declare the Future out de Build method / on the initState

_mainCategory State Widget

```
class _mainCategory extends State<subCategory> {
  Future _futureData;

  @override
  void initState() {
      super.initState();    
      _futureData = getRegister1();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
```

FutureBuilder inside Body

```
body: FutureBuilder(
  future: _futureData,
     builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer, possibly with example and explanation?

Comment: declare the future getRegister1() on the initState() and replace the future on futureBuilder with the var.

`
body: FutureBuilder(
            future: varFuture,
`

Comment: @Arcrueid I added `getRegister()` on the `initState()`. But How do I call `getRegister()` from `FutureBuilder( future:`

Comment: @Arcrueid Thanks for try to help me. I did it now. But still getRegister() running multiple times.

Comment: I added debug point for 1. `future: _futureData` and 2.`Future getRegister1() async{` first run `getRegister1()` and then `future: _futureData` and again two times run `getRegister1()` after that screen comes

Comment: after that, I clicked back button for move to the previous page, again running `future: _futureData` and clicked again back button again running `future: _futuData`. Why is that?

Comment: I think the problem is `future: _futureData` running two times. Why is that? I think I used two `await`.

Comment: I added screenshot also

Comment: I tried. Do you have any other solution to fix this?

Comment: I don't understand the screenshot...
but I think what you really want to do is keep the state.
see how to implement AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin